# Refactor if statement with object-oriented style

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, refactoring

I've this block of code:

```
if (memo.isEmail)
    doSomething();
if (memo.isSMS)
    doAnotherAction();
if (memo.isRecursive)
    doUpdateData();
```

A object "memo" can be either "mail" and "SMS", then the three conditions tested may all be true

How can I turn this procedural code in OO code? 
Is there a pattern to solve this?

Comment: This belongs in http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: And there's not nearly enough information.

Comment: Belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The OO conversion of a condition is a condition (with objects).

Comment: Upvoters of @ANeves - clicking 'close' is more constructive.

Comment: Rik's answer is fine, but you need to add a "Composite" to allow for a given memo to be more than one of the basic types at the same time. Check Wikipedia for Design Pattern "Composite"

Comment: @AndersJohansen - No, Rik's solution involves changing the class "memo", but I can not and I will not change it. I will use the CodeART's solution plus your Composit pattern (or list of processor?).
Grazie!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public interface IMemoProcessor
{ 
   void Run();
}

public class EmailMemoProcessor : IMemoProcessor
{
   public void Run()
   {
      // Send email
   }
}

public class SmsMemoProcessor : IMemoProcessor
{
   public void Run()
   {
      // Send sms
   }
}

// Factory looks at the type of memo and creates appropriate memo processor.
var memoProcessor = MemoProcessorFactory.Create(memo);
memoProcessor.Run();
```

Comment: A object "memo" can be either "mail" and "SMS", then the three conditions tested may all be true

Comment: Then factory can return a list of processors. You then iterate over processors and execute Run method.

Comment: @CodeART: then factory will include the same if conditions which OP has put in his question.

Comment: Conditions must be kept somewhere. Factory is an appropriate place in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The refactoring that generally applies to situations similar to this is [Replace Conditional With Polymorphism](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html), which would lead to code similar to that posted in Rik's answer.

This may only make sense if all of the choices are mutually exclusive, which isn't clear right now.

Comment: The choices are not mutually exclusive, there are no "return" after the procedures do....()